# menu item spacing issue in FF

Tags: css, firefox, menu, cross-browser

I have problems with spacing of my menu items in FF.
For some reason it doesnt take the normal spacing at first, but when I deselect and select for instance the padding style through the inspect element it shows and stay correct.

Correct layout in Chrome / IE / Safari:
[image]

Wrong layout in FF:
[image]

Am I missing or overlooking something?
Can someone help me to understand why this behaviour happens?

The issue can be found on https://www.giveaday.be

Any help or insights are much appreciated cause I'm really struggling on this point.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Looks like the layout is fine in old FF versions until updated to the FF quantum. With these version the weird spacing issue happens every page load.

Comment: It looks fine in Firefox on my computer. Could it be a cache problem on your computer? Which browser have you been using more for development?

Comment: I use mainly chrome for development. But even when I check in FF Incognito mode it looks like the spacing issue @MichaelBeeson

Comment: @MichaelBeeson testing on older version of FF it indeed shows without the spacing. Updated again to the FF Quantum V >57.0 and instantly it shows the wrong layout with spacing. On what version of FF did you check?